# Xcode6.1 UIImageView not being displayed properly

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimage, xcode6, image-resizing

I am not even sure how to google this issue. Images on my App are not being displayed fully. I'm looking to fit the full image within the 320 by 170 pixel constraint(or most of it). Right now all I can get is a cutoff version, no matter what I do to the image constraints, I can't seem to get this to work.

I have tried every mode and variation of tweaks google has to offer and that I can think of.

1. Screenshots: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVVnC.jpg

   @interface InzombImageCell ()

   ```
   @property AFHTTPRequestOperation* mediumImageOperation;

   @end

   @implementation InzombImageCell

   - (void)prepareForReuse {
     [super prepareForReuse];
     [self.mediumImageOperation cancel];
     self.mediumImageOperation = nil;
     self.mediumImageView.image = nil;
   }

   - (void)initializeCell {
     // define the medium size image URL
     NSURLRequest* mediumImageRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.image.mediumUrl]];

     // set the image response serializer for fetching the image
     AFImageResponseSerializer* mediumImageResponseSerializer = [AFImageResponseSerializer serializer];
     // automatically inflates the response image for better rendering time
     [mediumImageResponseSerializer setAutomaticallyInflatesResponseImage:YES];
     // set the image scale for retina displays
     [mediumImageResponseSerializer setImageScale:0.25];

     // set the self object because we don't want a retain cycle
     InzombImageCell* imageCell = self;

     [self.progressScroller startAnimating];
     // define the medium size image request
     self.mediumImageOperation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:mediumImageRequest];
     [self.mediumImageOperation setResponseSerializer:mediumImageResponseSerializer];
     [self.mediumImageOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, UIImage* responseObject) {
       [imageCell.mediumImageView setImage:responseObject];
       [imageCell.progressScroller stopAnimating];
     } failure:nil];
     [self.mediumImageOperation start];
   }
   ```

Comment: Looks like your image view's frame extends below your table view cell.

Comment: We thought the same thing. We are having a problem changing it. Do you have any advise or tips?

Comment: Actually... How are you adding that bar in each cell? Perhaps the are bars are covering up the images.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. They are implemented with the auto image constraints.

Comment: Huh? I'm talking about the bar seemingly attached to each cell (with up and down arrows, a flag, a username, etc.) How exactly are you adding that bar in each cell?

Comment: Apologies. I am a bit of a novice. All that data is contained in an .xib file that gets posted for every new image. http://i.imgur.com/IJsydvW.jpg

Comment: Could you add that code to your question?

Comment: @LyndseyScott Sorry that took so long (first time using the site). I believe this is what you asked for. Not sure if this what you are looking for though.

Comment: No... I wanted to see the code where you add the bar to your cell... probably in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: @LyndseyScott My fault. Updated.

Comment: @LyndseyScott My fault for wasting your time. This was a backend issue. Thank you anyways!